# Transpose data in a primeng datatable/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have an array of place which has these fields.(continent and country)

```
 places = [
           { "continent":"Europe", "country": "UK" },
           { "continent":"North America", "country": "US" },
           { "continent":"Asia", "country": "Philippines" },
           { "continent":"Africa", "country": "Egypt" }
          ];
```

If I plot it in a primeng datatable it something like this. 
   [image]

What I want is to transpose the data. I want the datatable to  be shown in the datatable in such that the continent row will become the header and the country will be the fields. Want I want is something like this.

[image]

I created a plunkr for this. http://plnkr.co/edit/KX1pCw?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a dynamic column primeNG Angular 2. Make column for each object in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607681/adding-a-dynamic-column-primeng-angular-2-make-column-for-each-object-in-the-ar)

Comment: @Aravind can you check my plunkr? I'm trying to do this but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your plunkr to work [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oZ7Lr?p=preview) .

html -

```
<p-dataTable [value]="places" sortMode="single" reorderableColumns="true" [globalFilter]="gb" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="350px">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}">
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

app.component.ts -

```
export class AppComponent {
  places_rawdata = 
          [
           { "continent":"Europe", "country": "UK" },
           { "continent":"North America", "country": "US" },
           { "continent":"Asia", "country": "Philippines" },
           { "continent":"Africa", "country": "Egypt" }
          ];

  places: any [] = [];
  cols:any[]=[];

  ngOnInit() {
    let temp: any = {};
    this.places=[];
    this.places_rawdata.forEach(
     (place,index) => {
       let s : string = 'country' + index;
       temp[s]= place.country
       this.cols.push({field: s, header: place.continent})
    });
    this.places = [...this.places,temp];
    console.log(this.places);
  }
}
```